# Bootstrap Navbar Search Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a search feature but the search feature is slightly below the rest of the items.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTZlH.jpg (Ops that Blog and Contact Me are active)

This is the code inside the navbar (with only home and search)

```
<!-- Navigation Links -->
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href = "../index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left form-inline" id="search" role="search">

                            <div class="form-group-group">
                                <<div class="input-group" style="width: 220px;">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><b class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search"></b></button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- END form group div -->

                        </form> <!-- END search bar form -->

                    </li>
                </ul> <!-- END navbar list -->

            </div> <!-- END navbar collapse div -->
```

Can anyone fix it so the search bar is on the same level as the other links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `<` sign here in your HTML, it can be spotted in your image as well:

```
    <<div class="input-group" style="width: 220px;">

--- ^ here ----------------------------------------
```

Remove it and you should be fine

Comment: Oh yeah I really should get round to installing SublimeLinter ;) it's all fixed, thank you!